# Android: multiple use of setOnSeekBarChangeListner method

Tags: java, android, android-seekbar

I have created a `Java` function called `AndroidSeekBar` which takes a seekbar_id , one textview_id and a type. type variable is used to call change `TextView` value for different SeekBars, here is he code:

```
public AndroidSeekBar(SeekBar id1, TextView textid,int type){
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

    PRICEbar = id1; // make seekbar object
    SeekValue = textid;
    int progress = PRICEbar.getProgress();
    if(type==1)
        progress = progress/5;
    else if(type==2)
        progress = progress*6;



    PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){ 

           @Override 
           public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, 
             boolean fromUser) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 

                        SeekValue.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 

           } 

           @Override 
           public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
           } 

           @Override 
           public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
           } 
               });
}
```

How can I pass *type* parameter into `setOnSeekBarChangeListener` function in order to set different string values for different SeekBars. for example at 40% progress if *type = 1* then It should set 40/5= `8 Meter` and on *type =2* it should set 40*6 = `240 Kg`.

Comment: Do any of the provided answers solve your problem? If so, please accept that answer. If not, please provide more guidance so the community can help you.

Answer (score 1):

> How can I pass type parameter into setOnSeekBarChangeListener function
>   in order to set different string values for different SeekBars

Use SeekBar.setTag(value) to access `type` value in `onProgressChanged` method :

```
PRICEbar.setTag(String.valueOf(type));
PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new 
                SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){ 

 @Override 
    public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, 
      int progress, boolean fromUser) { 
             int type=Integer.parseInt(seekBar.getTag().toString());

 }
... 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to make the method parameters final (i.e. texid, type) if you want to access them in the OnSeekBarChangeListener.

```
public AndroidSeekBar(SeekBar id1, final TextView textid, final int type){
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

PRICEbar = id1; // make seekbar object
SeekValue = textid;

PRICEbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener(){ 

       @Override 
       public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, 
           boolean fromUser) { 

            if(type==1)
                progress = progress/5;
            else if(type==2)
                progress = progress*6;
            textid.setText(String.valueOf(progress)); 

       } 

       @Override 
       public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
       } 

       @Override 
       public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) { 
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub 
       }

    });
}
```